# In Django CreateView use a class method to generate data to use in both get_context_data() and form_valid()

Tags: python, django, create-view

I'm actually working on a student project which i try to create a roguelike game on web using Python Django.

I'm actully confusing by my issue, to explain what i need to do is generate random characteristics in a character creation impacted by a choosen character class .

I want to send this characteristics to the user before he start the game. And use the characteristics I send him in my form_valid() to save the character in db.

I know that I a can use get_context_data() to send some information to my template but I don't know if can use the data send by get_context_data() to the template in form_valid().

Actually I'm succed with the a CreateView to save a character with random characteristics by a choosen character class, see the code bellow.

**models.py**

```
class CharacterClass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20,
                            blank=True,
                            null=True)
    minHpMax = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=10,
                                           validators=[MinValueValidator(10)],
                                           blank=False,
                                           null=False)
    minStrength = models.IntegerField(default=1,
                                      validators=[MinValueValidator(0)],
                                      blank=False,
                                      null=False)
    minAgility = models.IntegerField(default=1,
                                     validators=[MinValueValidator(0)],
                                     blank=False,
                                     null=False)
    minInt = models.IntegerField(default=1,
                                 validators=[MinValueValidator(0)],
                                 blank=False,
                                 null=False)
    minPhysResis = models.IntegerField(default=0,
                                       validators=[MinValueValidator(0)],
                                       blank=False,
                                       null=False)
    minMagRes = models.IntegerField(default=0,
                                    validators=[MinValueValidator(0)],
                                    blank=False,
                                    null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id}: {self.name}'

    def generateHpMax(self):
        return random.randint(self.minHpMax, self.minHpMax + 10)

    def generateStrength(self):
        return random.randint(self.minStrength, self.minStrength + 10)

    def generateAgility(self):
        return random.randint(self.minAgility, self.minAgility + 10)

    def generateIntelligence(self):
        return random.randint(self.minInt, self.minInt + 10)

    def generatePR(self):
        return random.randint(self.minPhysResis, self.minPhysResis + 10)

    def generateMR(self):
        return random.randint(self.minMagRes, self.minMagRes + 10)


class Character(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20,
                            default='Jon Doe',
                            blank=False,
                            null=False)
    characterClass = models.ForeignKey(CharacterClass,
                                       on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                       related_name='characterClass')
    level = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1,
                                        validators=[MinValueValidator(1)],
                                        blank=False,
                                        null=False)
    hpMax = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=10,
                                        validators=[MinValueValidator(0)],
                                        blank=False,
                                        null=False)
    hp = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=10,
                                     validators=[MinValueValidator(0)],
                                     blank=False,
                                     null=False)
    strength = models.IntegerField(default=1,
                                   validators=[MinValueValidator(0)],
                                   blank=False,
                                   null=False)
    agility = models.IntegerField(default=1,
                                  validators=[MinValueValidator(0)],
                                  blank=False,
                                  null=False)
    intelligence = models.IntegerField(default=1,
                                       validators=[MinValueValidator(0)],
                                       blank=False,
                                       null=False)
    physicalResistance = models.IntegerField(default=0,
                                             validators=[
                                                 MinValueValidator(0)],
                                             blank=False,
                                             null=False)
    magicalResistance = models.IntegerField(default=0,
                                            validators=[
                                                MinValueValidator(0)],
                                            blank=False,
                                            null=False)
    inventory = models.OneToOneField('Inventory',
                                     on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id}: {self.name} ' \
               f'[Lvl: {self.level}' \
               f'|Class: {self.characterClass}' \
               f'|HpM: {self.hpMax}' \
               f'|hp: {self.hp}' \
               f'|Str: {self.strength}' \
               f'|Ag: {self.agility}' \
               f'|Int: {self.intelligence}' \
               f'|Pr: {self.physicalResistance}' \
               f'|Mr: {self.magicalResistance}]'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('characterDetail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**views.py**

```
    class GenerateCharacterView(CreateView):
    model = Character
    form_class = CharacterForm
    template_name = 'characterForm.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Creation of Character without db saving
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)

        # creation of empty inventory unique for the Character
        inventory = Inventory()
        inventory.save()
        self.object.inventory = inventory

        pkCharacterClass= form['characterClass'].value()
        currentCharacterClass = get_object_or_404(CharacterClass,
                                                  pk=pkCharacterClass)

        # for a CharacterClass found, get random characteristics for the Character in creation
        generatedHpMax = currentCharacterClass.generateHpMax()
        self.object.hpMax = generatedHpMax
        self.object.hp = generatedHpMax

        generatedStrength = currentCharacterClass.generateStrength()
        self.object.strength = generatedStrength

        generatedAgility = currentCharacterClass.generateAgility()
        self.object.agility = generatedAgility

        generatedIntelligence = currentCharacterClass.generateIntelligence()
        self.object.intelligence = generatedIntelligence

        generatedPhysicalResistance = currentCharacterClass.generatePR()
        self.object.physicalResistance = generatedPhysicalResistance

        generatedMagicalResistance = currentCharacterClass.generateMR()
        self.object.magicalResistance = generatedMagicalResistance

        # Enregistrement en BDD de l'objet et appel du super form valid pour
        # renvoie de la succes url défini en Model
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**forms.py**

```
    class CharacterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Character
        # exclude = []
        fields = ['name', 'characterClass']

    name = forms.CharField(max_length=20, widget=widgets.TextInput(
        attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Your Name'}
    ))
```

**urls.py**

```
    urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', IndexView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('generateCharacter',
         GenerateCharacterView.as_view(),
         name='generateCharacter'),
    path('characterDetail/<int:pk>', CharacterDetailView.as_view(),
         name='characterDetail'),
]
```

Did you already succeed this kind of use ? 
Did you know if it's working ? and how ? 
Did you had some tips or advices for me ? I'm working on it form 2 days now and i'm going crazy.

---

Hello sorry for the this ticket, I may a mistake in what I show in it.

For now i use the code that I show in ticket for overpass my issue.

At this moment i can generate a character with random characteristics by choising a CharacterClass and a character name.

But what i want to do is generate the random characteristics when I come in the form page.

So i try to put on a page a button who call a path 'createCharacter/1' where '1' is the pk of my character class.

And i tried to generate the radom characteristics at this moment to show to the user the characteristics before the submit of the form.

And in the form only asked the character name.

So this was the code that I used previously

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', IndexView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('createCharacter/<int:characterClass>',
         CreateCharacterView.as_view(),
         name='createCharacter'),
    path('characterDetail/<int:pk>', CharacterDetailView.as_view(),
         name='characterDetail'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class CreateCharacterView(CreateView):
    model = Character
    form_class = CharacterForm
    template_name = 'characterForm.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        classCharacter = get_object_or_404(CharacterClass ,self.kwargs['characterClass'])
        context['randomCarac'] = classCharacter.getRadomCarac()
        return context 

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)


        inventory = Inventory()
        inventory.save()
        self.object.inventory = inventory


        self.object.characterClass= context['characterClass']
        self.object.hpMax = context['hpMax ']
        self.object.hp = context['hpMax ']
        self.object.strength = context['strength ']
        self.object.agility = context['agility ']
        self.object.intelligence = context['intelligence  ']
        self.object.physicalResistance = context['physicalResistance ']
        self.object.magicalResistance = context['magicalResistance ']

        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**models.py**

```
class CharacterClass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20,
                            blank=True,
                            null=True)
    minHpMax = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=10,
                                           validators=[MinValueValidator(10)],
                                           blank=False,
                                           null=False)
    minStrength = models.IntegerField(default=1,
                                      validators=[MinValueValidator(0)],
                                      blank=False,
                                      null=False)
    minAgility = models.IntegerField(default=1,
                                     validators=[MinValueValidator(0)],
                                     blank=False,
                                     null=False)
    minInt = models.IntegerField(default=1,
                                 validators=[MinValueValidator(0)],
                                 blank=False,
                                 null=False)
    minPhysResis = models.IntegerField(default=0,
                                       validators=[MinValueValidator(0)],
                                       blank=False,
                                       null=False)
    minMagRes = models.IntegerField(default=0,
                                    validators=[MinValueValidator(0)],
                                    blank=False,
                                    null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id}: {self.name}'

    def generateHpMax(self):
        return random.randint(self.minHpMax, self.minHpMax + 10)

    def generateStrength(self):
        return random.randint(self.minStrength, self.minStrength + 10)

    def generateAgility(self):
        return random.randint(self.minAgility, self.minAgility + 10)

    def generateIntelligence(self):
        return random.randint(self.minInt, self.minInt + 10)

    def generatePR(self):
        return random.randint(self.minPhysResis, self.minPhysResis + 10)

    def generateMR(self):
        return random.randint(self.minMagRes, self.minMagRes + 10)

    def getRadomCarac(self):
        return {'hpMax': self.generateHpMax(),
                'strength': self.generateStrength(),
                'agility': self.generateAgility(),
                'intelligence': self.generateIntelligence(),
                'physicalResistance': self.generatePR(),
                'magicalResistance': self.getRadomCarac()}
```

---

That doesn't work.
It seems i don't have acces to my context['something'] in the form_validation()

So i also tried to

```
class CreateCharacterView(CreateView):
    model = Character
    form_class = CharacterForm
    template_name = 'characterForm.html'
    classCharacter = get_object_or_404(CharacterClass ,self.kwargs['characterClass'])
    randomCarac = classCharacter.getRadomCarac()

def form_valid(self, form):
        # Do things here with randomCarac['something']
```

to have the value 'global' in the View to use when i want, the get_object_or_404() don't work

Comment: What exactly isn't working with the code you're showing? Are there errors? Is something shown that shouldn't be shown? It's not clear what's the actual problem. You more or less explained what you want, but not what the actual problem is.

Comment: A good problem statement is like this: "I want to achieve <this>; I tried <code>; but when I go to <this url> I see <this> instead of <that>".

Comment: Ok sorry for my post i do some edit to show what i tried.
My first sending show what i've done to overpass my issue and do what i need and don't what i really want to do

Comment: Again you're not telling us what was wrong with the previous code. It didn't work? It gave an error? It didn't behave as expected? You can't expect us to read code and immediately figure out what it does.

Comment: Yes that doesn't work.
It seems i don't have acces to my context['something'] in the form_validation()

So i also tried to 
```
class CreateCharacterView(CreateView):
    model = Character
    form_class = CharacterForm
    template_name = 'characterForm.html'
    classCharacter = get_object_or_404(CharacterClass ,self.kwargs['characterClass'])
    randomCarac = classCharacter.getRadomCarac()
    
     
```

Comment: Of course not, `context` isn't defined in the `form_valid()` method. There isn't a single line in that method where `context` is defined.

Comment: Yes that doesn't work.
It seems i don't have acces to my context['something'] in the form_validation()

So i also tried to 
```
class CreateCharacterView(CreateView):
    model = Character
    form_class = CharacterForm
    template_name = 'characterForm.html'
    classCharacter = get_object_or_404(CharacterClass ,self.kwargs['characterClass'])
    randomCarac = classCharacter.getRadomCarac()
    
def form_valid(self, form):
        # Do things here with randomCarac['something']
```

to have the value 'global' in the View to use when i want, the get_object_or_404() don't work

Comment: The problem is even if you get this right, you'll be creating a random character when the `CreateView` renders the form (GET request) and you'll be creating it again (and it will be **different**) when you process the submitted form (POST request). Those requests are separate and you cannot expect anything done during the form rendering to be kept in the next request.

Comment: So if I understand what you saying. If I want to send the data to the user I have to do it in `get_context_data()` in the template i set a input with `value="{{ something }}"` and when the user submit the form i can use the data in `form_valid()` in POST mode.

The thing is that the user can cheat with F12 command and change the value i had generated

Comment: What does F12 do? Just curious, it doesn't do anything in my browser.

Comment: Open the Devtools of the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a random character when the form is shown to the user **and keep that random character** to save when the user submits the form (the name of the character), you'll need to **persist** the random character somehow.

You have a couple of options:

1. Create and save the character already when rendering the form the first time with the GET request (with a blank name) and include the id of the character in the form as hidden field so that when you submit the form you **update** the character with the name. 
   You'll want to check that submitted `id` belongs to a "draft" character somehow in order to be sure the user doesn't steal another already existing character, so you might need to add a `status` field to your `Character` model. You would not use the `CreateView` here but a function-based view would be more appropriate.
2. You create the values for the character in the `get()` method of your view and store them in the `request.session` (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/sessions/)) so that you can retrieve said values from the session in the `form_valid()` method. This method seems easier to me. You can still use the `CreateView` here. You can display them in your template either directly using `{{ request.session.<somekey> }}` or by adding them to your context in `get_context_data()` in a format that might be easier to render in your template.

Submitting the random values via hidden form input fields is not an option, because anyone can always tamper the values submitted.

Note that I don't understand why your `Character` model doesn't have a reference to the `User` (`ForeignKey` or `OneToOneField`). It's not clear how you can check that the character **belongs** to this user and avoid a user stealing someone else's character. If you add this, then in option 1 you don't even need to check for an `id` since `request.user` can only have one "draft" `Character`.

Comment: Ok thx I think I understand what you say here.
I gonna try the option 2, because I don't want to polluate my db with may non used Character

Comment: For the `User` reference i do this in an other class. The `Party` class where I gonna had the `User` and `Character` in OneToOneField

Comment: And in a future of this project the party gonna be created directly after the user creation which is trigger by the form submit
.
At the end we target this workflow:
CreateCharacter -> CreateParty -> PlayTheParty -> EndGame -> SaveScore

It gonna be a game with an unique character for an oneshoot party

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys this is the final code who work in my project

***url.py***

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', IndexView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('generateCharacterByPk/<int:pk>', GenerateCharacterView2.as_view(),
         name='generateCharacterByPk'),
    path('generateCharacter', GenerateCharacterView.as_view(),
         name='generateCharacter'),
    path('characterDetail/<int:pk>', CharacterDetailView.as_view(),
         name='characterDetail'),
]
```

***forms.py***

```
class CharacterForm2(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Character
        # exclude = []
        fields = ['name']

    name = forms.CharField(max_length=20, widget=widgets.TextInput(
        attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Your Name'}
    ))
```

***views.py***

```
class GenerateCharacterView2(CreateView):
    model = Character
    form_class = CharacterForm2
    template_name = 'characterForm.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        result = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        result['title'] = 'Create Character'
        return result

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        currentCharacterClass = get_object_or_404(CharacterClass,
                                                  pk=self.kwargs['pk'])

        self.request.session['characterClass'] = self.kwargs['pk']
        self.request.session['HpMax'] = currentCharacterClass.generateHpMax()
        self.request.session['Strength'] = currentCharacterClass.generateStrength()
        self.request.session['Agility'] = currentCharacterClass.generateAgility()
        self.request.session['Intelligence'] = currentCharacterClass.generateIntelligence()
        self.request.session['PhysicalResistance'] = currentCharacterClass.generatePR()
        self.request.session['MagicalResistance'] = currentCharacterClass.generateMR()
        return super().get(self)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Création de l'objet sans enregistrement en base
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)

        # Création d'un inventaire vide unique au personnage avec affectation et récupéraction de la classe du personnage
        currentCharacterClass = get_object_or_404(CharacterClass,
                                                  pk=self.request.session['characterClass'])
        inventory = Inventory()
        inventory.save()

        # Constitution du personnage
        self.object.inventory = inventory
        self.object.characterClass = currentCharacterClass
        self.object.hpMax = self.request.session['HpMax']
        self.object.hp = self.request.session['HpMax']
        self.object.strength = self.request.session['Strength']
        self.object.agility = self.request.session['Agility']
        self.object.intelligence = self.request.session['Intelligence']
        self.object.physicalResistance = self.request.session['PhysicalResistance']
        self.object.magicalResistance = self.request.session['MagicalResistance']

        # Création en BDD du personnage
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

***characterForm.html***

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block page-top %}


    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in form %}
            <div class="h5 font-weight-bold text-primary text-uppercase mb-1">
                <label>
                    {{ field.label }}:
                </label>
                <nav>
                    {{ field }}
                </nav>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}

        {{ request.session.characterClass }}
        {{ request.session.HpMax }}
        {{ request.session.Strength }}
        {{ request.session.Intelligence }}
        {{ request.session.Agility }}
        {{ request.session.PhysicalResistance }}
        {{ request.session.MagicalResistance }}
        <button type="submit">Valider</button>
    </form>


{% endblock %}
```

Thx @dirkgroten for your help, it was realy helpfull

Answer (score 0):

May miss something in your solution, I've tried the solution 2, and i write the code bellow

***index.html***

```
    <button>
        <a href="{% url 'generateCharacterByPk' 1 %}">Play2(pk=1)</a>
    </button>

    <button>
        <a href="{% url 'generateCharacterByPk' 2 %}">Play2(pk=2)</a>
    </button>
```

***urls.py***

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', IndexView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('generateCharacterByPk/<int:pk>',
         GenerateCharacterView2.as_view(),
         name='generateCharacterByPk'),
    path('generateCharacter',
         GenerateCharacterView.as_view(),
         name='generateCharacter'),
    path('characterDetail/<int:pk>', CharacterDetailView.as_view(),
         name='characterDetail'),
]
```

***forms.py***

```
class CharacterForm2(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Character
        # exclude = []
        fields = ['name']

    name = forms.CharField(max_length=20, widget=widgets.TextInput(
        attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Your Name'}
    ))
```

***views.py***

```
class GenerateCharacterView2(CreateView):
    model = Character
    form_class = CharacterForm2
    template_name = 'characterForm.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        result = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        result['title'] = 'Create Character'
        return result

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.session.characterClass = self.kwargs['pk']
        currentCharacterClass = get_object_or_404(CharacterClass,
                                                  pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        request.session.characterClass = currentCharacterClass
        request.session.HpMax = currentCharacterClass.generateHpMax()
        request.session.Strength = currentCharacterClass.generateStrength()
        request.session.Agility = currentCharacterClass.generateAgility()
        request.session.Intelligence = currentCharacterClass.generateIntelligence()
        request.session.PhysicalResistance = currentCharacterClass.generatePR()
        request.session.MagicalResistance = currentCharacterClass.generateMR()
        return render(request, 'characterForm.html')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Création de l'objet sans enregistrement en base
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)

        # Création d'un inventaire vide unique au personnage avec affectation
        inventory = Inventory()
        inventory.save()

        self.object.inventory = inventory
        self.object.hpMax = request.session.characterClass
        self.object.hpMax = request.session.HpMax
        self.object.hp = request.session.HpMax
        self.object.strength = request.session.Strength
        self.object.agility = request.session.Agility
        self.object.intelligence = request.session.Intelligence
        self.object.physicalResistance = request.session.PhysicalResistance
        self.object.magicalResistance = request.session.MagicalResistance

        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

***characterForm.html***

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block page-top %}


    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in form %}
            <div class="h5 font-weight-bold text-primary text-uppercase mb-1">
                <label>
                    {{ field.label }}:
                </label>
                <nav>
                    {{ field }}
                </nav>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}

        {{ request.session.characterClass }}
        {{ request.session.HpMax }}
        {{ request.session.Strength }}
        {{ request.session.Intelligence }}
        {{ request.session.Agility }}
        {{ request.session.PhysicalResistance }}
        {{ request.session.MagicalResistance }}
        <button type="submit">Valider</button>
    </form>


{% endblock %}
```

And I have a weird reaction when I access to generateCharacterByPk/1 or generateCharacterByPk/2

First I see the random features randomly generated by my get on my page with a submit button.

When I click on the reload page and I end up with my form and a submit button but I don't see the features on my page anymore.

And when I validate the form, I get the following error:

````
AttributeError at /generateCharacterByPk/1
module 'django.http.request' has no attribute 'session'.
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/generateCharacterByPk/1
Django Version: 3.0.2
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
module 'django.http.request' has no attribute 'session'.
Exception Location: C:\Users\u049298\Desktop\PYTHON_DJANGO\projetWebRPG\app\views.py in form_valid, line 130
```
````

Comment: Ok I changed the return of my def get() in `return super().get(self, request)` and it resolve the first issue i go directly on the form with my random characteristics

But the second error when i submit my form still here. And i don't know why